# Why for loop in Console doesn't run?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am pretty new to JavaScript Selector, and I hope to know why the "for loop" below doesn't work in the console?

```
for(var i=0;i<=24;i++)
{document.getElementsByClassName("srr-title")[i].innerHTML}
```

Thanks!

Comment: how many elements with with class `srr-title` do you have?

Comment: ***How*** doesn't it work? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: The getElementsBy* methods return HTMLCollections, which can be difficult to work with. Consider using querySelectorAll instead, which returns a static NodeList - unlike an HTMLCollection, it can be iterated over directly, it won't change while it's being iterated over, and it's much more flexible.

Comment: `for(var i=0;i<=24;i++)
    console.log("Hello")` works fine by me. Please specify how your code doesn't work and which error you got.

Comment: it does work ... what do you expect the result to be. As you do nothing, your result is nothing - did you want to `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("srr-title")[i].innerHTML)` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed console.log()

```
for(var i=0;i<=24;i++)
{
   console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("srr-title")[i].innerHTML);
// above code will print the value on console
}
```